# Bootstrap form validation not not working on set of number fields for date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I have these three fields for date:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 form-group col-sm-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control birth-day" id="dan_rodjenja" name="dan_rodjenja" max="31" min="1" placeholder="DD" required type="number" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control birth-month" id="mjesec_rodjenja" max="12" min="1" name="mjesec_rodjenja" placeholder="MM" required type="number" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control birth-year" id="godina_rodjenja" max="2000" min="1910" name="godina_rodjenja" placeholder="GGGG" required type="number" value="" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

For example, if the first and second fields are filled and the third one is empty, I get no errors (no red borders). Or when I leave the first field empty, all three show errors. Could someone help me with this?

I am using bootstrap validation  http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/.

Comment: When one of the fields is empty, you want red border only on empty field or you want red border on all fields?

Comment: I want red border only on the fields that do not pass validation (that is left empty or the number is out of range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` element, that is **direct parent of input element** with class `.form-control` must have class `.form-group` (as structure below).

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" ... />
</div>
```

So your code look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control birth-day" id="dan_rodjenja" name="dan_rodjenja" max="31" min="1" placeholder="DD" required type="number" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
             <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control birth-month" id="mjesec_rodjenja" max="12" min="1" name="mjesec_rodjenja" placeholder="MM" required type="number" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control birth-year" id="godina_rodjenja" max="2000" min="1910" name="godina_rodjenja" placeholder="GGGG" required type="number" value="" />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```